# Submarine record from WW2

Tags: world-war-two, historiography, submarine

I am trying to find an original submarine record sent from submarine to the HQ which includes location, movement, weather, orders and details about the submarine during World War 2. I am trying to find a draft that is being used during war so that I can examine the way they were written.

What were submarine logs and records like in World War II? And is there any source where I can find a copy or facsimile of an original document? There is no specific submarine I am looking for.

Comment: Any submarine or one in particular? In whose navy?

Comment: Good luck with your search - is there a question you'd like answered?

Comment: Please clarify the question.

Comment: I have (hopefully) clarified the question.

Comment: What Country's Navy, please?

Answer (score 2):

I think the documents in https://maritime.org/doc/subreports.htm
might come close to what you want.